# Password box IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled showing checkbox in custom style

Tags: xaml, passwords, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I was using following code for password box it shows reveal password checkbox that is what i whant.

```
<PasswordBox x:Uid="Password" Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="True"> </PasswordBox>
```

Now as a requirement I need to use different color on passwordbox foucs, so I have to update the default template of the password box. I got the default templete from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710188.aspx). and updated the focus visual state to change the background color. Now instead of password revealed CheckBox a button is showing inside the passsowrd box(which also goes away once it is pressed).

I want to show the password revealed check box instead of button in side the box. How can I achieve this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems indeed that the template provided on MSDN doesn't match the default one on Windows Phone. But you can easily extract it using Blend.

Here is the exact template, that you can modify to suit your needs:

```
    <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinWidth">51</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinHeight">33</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">2.5001</Thickness>
    <FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilyNormal">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
    <x:Double x:Key="ContentControlFontSize">20.26</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlThemePadding">7,2.5,8,4</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlMarginThemeThickness">0,9.5,0,9.5</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness">0,0,0,4.8</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="RichEditBoxTextThemeMargin">2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="PasswordBoxCheckBoxThemeMargin">0,-6.5,0,0</Thickness>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextControlBackgroundThemeOpacity">0.8</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeOpacity">0.8</x:Double>
    <Style x:Key="PasswordBoxStyle" TargetType="PasswordBox">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlMarginThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PasswordBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="RevealButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked" Storyboard.TargetName="RevealButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="RevealButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked" Storyboard.TargetName="RevealButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" Margin="{ThemeResource RichEditBoxTextThemeMargin}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{ThemeResource RichEditBoxTextThemeMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="RevealButton" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundHeaderThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{ThemeResource PasswordBoxCheckBoxThemeMargin}" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: for check box if I set's IsChecked=True than password box is alwasy visible.... How can i fix that in style...?